# Composing a list of functions into the current context

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am quite new to Clojurescript and LISPy languages, so please excuse my imperative way of thinking.

I'm using Raphael.js to draw some things. It lets you define a set, push things into the set (say, a circle, a rectangle, and a path), and then perform an operation that acts upon all items (example: a rotation that applies to all).

So we can have (where `paper` is basically the svg element):

```
(-> (.set paper) 
    (.push (.ellipse paper 10 10 10 10))
    (.push (.circle paper 10 10 10 10))
    (.transform (format "r%.2f" 180)))
```

Which will create a set and use multiple calls to `push` which returns the set each time, eventually calling `transform`. Now what if I want to create a list of say `circle` objects at runtime and add them to the set? What i'd ideally like to be able to do is to replace say line 3 of the above code block with something like (very roughly - i'm completely unsure about how to deal with the `.push`)

```
(.push (map (fn [i] (.ellipse paper 10 (* i 10) 10 10)) (range 5)))
```

in order to create 5 circles coming down the y axis. What I can't quite figure out with my limited grasp of Clojure is how to do such a thing in a fairly idomatic way without resorting to a `doseq` somewhere else. I don't want side effects. I'd like to somehow create a list of pushes and then have them all compose themselves into my block in-place. Is that possible? There may be a huge flaw in my thinking somewhere and I'd be really very grateful to anyone who can point that out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding side effects is a little tricky since `push` apparently mutates the set. One way to avoid `doseq` is to use `reduce`. For example:

```
(def shapes [ (.circle paper 10 10 10 10) (.ellipse paper 10 10 10 10) ] )

(defn push-all [set shapes] 
  (reduce #(.push %1 %2) set shapes))

(-> (.set paper) 
    (push-all shapes)
    (.transform (format "r%.2f" 180)))
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. I was trying to use `reduce` to perform this at one point. I was a little off saying that I wanted to avoid side effects as you are correct in saying that `.push` mutates the state anyway. I unfortunately do not have enough reputation to upvote you so I'm sending you some real-life karma instead.